# Downloading file from S3 using python SDK

Tags: boto3

I have created a function to download files from S3. THe logic is that: I list buckets, select bucket, then list file and then choose a file to download, however, I encounter the error.  That bucket is empty, or some other errors when I try to implement different code. Probably issue is super simple I just can't see it. please help. Commented code is another code I have tried. The selection of the bucket and file works the way it is supposed to and is outputs with printing the correct name of the file into the console interface.

```
def function_for_f(s3_handle=None):
    ##list buckets
    ## list files then
    ##download the file
    selected_bucket_name_origin = select_buckets(s3_handle=s3_handle)
    print(f"Selected bucket was: {selected_bucket_name_origin}")
    # Retrieve the bucket's objects
    objects = list_bucket_objects_aws(s3_handle=s3_handle, bucket_name=selected_bucket_name_origin)
    if objects is not None:
        obj_count=0
        # List the object names
        for obj in objects:
            print(f'{obj_count}. {obj["Key"]}')
            obj_count = obj_count + 1
        
        if obj_count > 0:
            object_to_copy_index = input('Which object to copy?')
        print(f'Dowloading {objects[int(object_to_copy_index)]["Key"]}')
        # # Download the object
        # try:
        #     s3_handle.Bucket(selected_bucket_name_origin).download_file(objects[int(object_to_copy_index)]["Key"], 'my_local_image.jpg')
        # except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        #     if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
        #         print("The object does not exist.")
        #     else:
        #         raise
    
        if s3_handle.download_file(selected_bucket_name_origin, objects[int(object_to_copy_index)]["Key"], '1.txt'):
                 logging.info(f'{obj["Key"]} was dowloaded from {selected_bucket_name_origin}')            

        else:
            print('Bucket is empty')
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: I'm getting code from else statement. Bucket is empty, so for some reason my if block doesnt kick in